# RWeka Issue Knitting HTML

Tags: r, rstudio, rweka

I'm getting the error below involving the RWeka library, when trying to knit a markdown file into html with Knitr in Rstudio.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

> Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>    call: fun(libname, pkgname)
>    error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
>   Quitting from lines 14-20 (Milestone_Report.Rmd)
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for 'RWeka'
>   Execution halted

Comment: What happens if you call `library(RWeka)` in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Please install latest version of Java and set value for JAVA_HOME variable as the directory where you installed Java. Once done try library(RWeka) and see if you are getting error. Hope this should solve the problem.